# What are some useful examples of extension methods dealing with mathematics and calculations?

Tags: c#, math, extension-methods

My very often used extension method is

```
public static double Pi(double this x) { return Math.PI*x; }
```

in order to have access to `2.0.Pi()` or `0.5.Pi()` .. etc

What are some other examples of mathematics related extension methods the people use often?

PS. Just curious.

Comment: Maybe you should try Ruby or another language.

Comment: @leppie Why? Or are you just trollin'?

Comment: Useful === things you need. What you need us specific to you; so... What do you need?? I use precious little "Pi" for example.

Comment: IMO, `2.0 * Math.PI` is much clearer than `2.0.Pi()` (which reads something like "two point zero point π")

Comment: You are trying to use C# like another language.

Comment: There was some push-back against using extension methods to obfuscate code in the early days of C# 3.0.  But good lord, there's no stopping this.  Time for an authority to publish an "Extension methods considered harmful" paper.

Comment: Voted to close, should be a blog post.

Comment: The point is not to obfuscate code, but to condese it. For example since C# does not support exponent operator (Like ** in FORTRAN) an extension method will alow to do `x.Raise(3)` instead of `x*x*x` or `Math.Pow(x,3)` which IMHO is easier to read.

Comment: I am being honest here. I want to know examples of how the community has used extension methods to make math easier to write in C#. Is this a bad place to ask such a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the creative juices flowing I will offer some more examples...

```
public static double Raise(double this x, double exponent)
{
    return Math.Pow(x, exponent);
}

public static bool NearZero(double this x, double tolerance)
{
     return Math.Abs(x) <= tolerance;
}

public static double Cap(double this x, double threshold)
{
    return Math.Abs(x)<threshold ? x : threshold*Math.Sign(x);
}

public static double SignOf(double this x, double sense)
{
    return Math.Sign(sense)*Math.Abs(x);
}

public static double ToRadians(double this x) { return Math.PI*x/180; }
public static double ToDegrees(double this x) { return 180*x/Math.PI; }
```

PS. Thanks @Aaron for posting extensionmethods.net. Unfortunately they have little in terms of math related postings.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static double Squared(double this x) { return x*x; }
```

Comment: Very good example considering the limitations of the C# syntax to square, cube or raise a power.

Comment: My first thought was why not just write x ^ 2 in code, rather than x.Squared()?  Fewer characters, and arguably just as clear.  But I can see this being useful if, say, a function returns a double... circle.Radius.Squared().PI().  Interesting